# Assigning a binary value to a row based on difference in time-stamp value from row to row

Tags: r, datetime, timestamp, calculated-columns

I would like to create a new, binary column which indicates how long it has been since the previous point. I need a row value of 1 if it has been less than 7000 seconds since the previous point and a value of 0 if it has been more than 7000 seconds since the previous point. Each row has a date-time stamp of form POSIXct however I have created a vector of seconds if that makes it easier to work.

My data is as follows:

```
structure(list(datetime = c("2015/1/06 17:51:17", "2015/1/06 19:51:17", 
                            "2015/1/06 21:46:38", "2015/1/06 21:51:18", "2015/1/06 21:56:26", 
                            "2015/1/06 22:1:27", "2015/1/06 22:4:27", "2015/1/06 22:7:27", 
                            "2015/1/06 22:10:27", "2015/1/06 22:15:31", "2015/1/06 22:18:30", 
                            "2015/1/06 22:21:30", "2015/1/06 22:24:39", "2015/1/06 22:27:38", 
                            "2015/1/06 22:31:27", "2015/1/06 22:34:54", "2015/1/06 22:38:57", 
                            "2015/1/06 22:43:6", "2015/1/06 22:48:14", "2015/1/06 22:53:16"
), secs = c(1420566677, 1420573877, 1420580798, 1420581078, 1420581386, 
            1420581687, 1420581867, 1420582047, 1420582227, 1420582531, 1420582710, 
            1420582890, 1420583079, 1420583258, 1420583487, 1420583694, 1420583937, 
            1420584186, 1420584494, 1420584796), lat = c(57.601675, 57.601591, 
                                                         57.602044, 57.603132, 57.6053, 57.608035, 57.609892, 57.612037, 
                                                         57.613997, 57.615203, 57.617153, 57.618842, 57.62074, 57.621673, 
                                                         57.623699, 57.625592, 57.628001, 57.630123, 57.633267, 57.634734
            ), lon = c(-4.034009, -4.033829, -4.036087, -4.039707, -4.043336, 
                       -4.046311, -4.047127, -4.047383, -4.047484, -4.047528, -4.046922, 
                       -4.046935, -4.046753, -4.04651, -4.045886, -4.045272, -4.044616, 
                       -4.044387, -4.044233, -4.042613)), .Names = c("datetime", "secs", 
                                                                     "lat", "lon"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try `library(data.table);setDT(dfN)[, bin:=+(secs-shift(secs, fill=secs[1L]) < 7000)]`

Comment: 1- Your `datetime` is not `POSIXct` class. 2- Your seconds column doesn't make any sense and it is way too big. 3- Just use `+(c(0, diff(as.POSIXct(df$datetime))) < 7000)` and get over with.

Comment: @akrun Thanks, that works great. Is there a way to take it a step further and only assign a value of 1 if not only the time between the N and N-1 is 7000 but also the time between N and N+1 is 7000?

Comment: @DavidArenburg The seconds column does make sense sequentially it just begins with a large number due to the inferred start time of the entire data-set (1970). The numbers are sound. That code does work, thank you but is there a way to take it a step further as mentioned above? (only assign a value of 1 if not only the time between N and N-1 is 7000 but also the time between N and N+1 is 7000)

Comment: Will check it later  Have to go.

Comment: @JojoOne Try with `setDT(dfN)[, bin:= +(secs-shift(secs, fill=secs[1L]) <7000|secs-shift(secs, type='lead', fill=secs[.N]) <7000)]`